# is there a an example code or plugin that can help find out how to play audio files listview builder?

Tags: android, flutter, listview, audio, plugins

I have created a list view builder with items as songs.Each of the items have a play arrow ,duration and current position of song/audio. I couldn't able to play these audios in any of the attempts. How could i resolve this with a suitable plugin or example code. I have already tried assets audio player. and also the audio player must have null safety and able to play audio from links.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio Is good one supports all platforms check it out

Comment: yeah, that is a nice plugin but , audioplayers plugin met my requirement